# How to make a list of prices for a receipt?

Tags: python

I've been trying for a while to make my receipt to show all the prices I listed,using sum() to show subtotal, and make a dollar sign next to my prices. So far I have a lot of my receipt done, but can't figure this out. This is my code so far:

```
price = []

headphones = int(input("Enter price of Headphones: ") )
while(True):
    price = int(input("Enter price of Headphones: "))
    if (price == -1):
       break
apple= int(input("Enter price of  Apple: ") )
while(True):
    price = int(input("Enter price of  Apple: "))
    if (price == -1):
      break
pen = int(input("Enter price of Pen: ") )
while(True):
    price = int(input("Enter price of Pen: "))
    if (price == -1):
       break
mouse = int(input("Enter price of  Mouse: ") )
while(True):
    price = int(input("Enter price of  Mouse: "))
    if (price == -1):
       break
paper = int(input("Enter price of amount for Paper: ") )
while(True):
    price = int(input("Enter price of amount for Paper: "))
    if (price == -1):
       break
cookies = int(input("Enter price of Cookies: ") )
while(True):
    price = int(input("Enter price of Cookies: "))
    if (price == -1):
       break
bananas = int(input("Enter price of Bananas: ") )
while(True):
    price = int(input("Enter price of Bananas:"))
    if (price == -1):
       break
bread = int(input("Enter price of Bread: ") )
while(True):
    price = int(input("Enter price of Bread: "))
    if (price == -1):
       break

subtotal = headphones + apple + pen + mouse + paper + cookies + bananas + bread
tax = int(subtotal * 0.065)
total = subtotal + tax

a = headphones
b = apple
c = pen
d = mouse
e = paper
f = cookies
g = bananas
h = bread
w = subtotal

y = w * .065
v = y+w

print("Target Recipt".center(80, "-"))
print("-".center(80, "-"))

print("Headphones                        $:   ".center(0, ), headphones)
print("Apple                             $:   ".center(0, ), apple)
print("Pen                               $:   ".center(0, ), pen)
print("Mouse                             $:   ".center(0, ), mouse)
print("Paper                             $:   ".center(0, ), paper)
print("Cookies                           $:   ".center(0, ), cookies)
print("Bananas                           $:   ".center(0, ), bananas)
print("Bread                             $:   ".center(0, ), bread)

print("-".center(80, "-"))
print()
print()
print("Subtotal".center(37, ), w)
print("Tax".center(37, ), y)
print()
print("Total".center(37, ), v)
print()
print()
print('Have a wonderful day!'.center(80, "-"))
```

I can't seem to figure out what what I'm doing wrong. I know that I'm supposed to use this:

```
prices = []

while(True):
    p = float(input("Enter a price" ))
    prices.append(p)

for i in range(len(prices)):
    print(prices[i])
```

Comment: So you only accepts items that are `price` at `-1` only?

Comment: You have a `while True:` with no `break` there.

Comment: What is the issue with the code you are *supposed* to use?

Comment: The -1 breaks it so it won't continue. The issue is that I need to make a list and add dollar signs.

Comment: One major problem is that after initializing `price = []` the code then reassigns the integer value `-1` to it in each of `while(True)` loops that follow. This means `price` is no longer a list when they've finished execution.

Comment: Ok, thank-you! I fixed it.